# How to switch Scene in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have 2 Scenes, "one scene is just an empty scene with a button" and "another scene has one TableView". I would like to switch back and forth, my code that is using to switch the scenes is 
shown below:

```
scence1 to scene2
    auto scene2 = Scene2::createScene();
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene2);

scene2 to scene1
    auto scene1 = Scene1::createScene();
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(scene1);
```

I suspect that TableViewCell make the program crashes.

Here is my code to create TableView in scene2:

```
Size tvSize = Size(640.0, 640.0);
_tableview = TableView::create(this, tvSize);
_tableview->retain();
_tableview->setDirection(cocos2d::extension::ScrollView::Direction::VERTICAL);
_tableview->setPosition(Point(0.0 , 0.0 + ((640.0 - tvSize.height)/ 2.0)));
_tableview->setDataSource(this);
```

Remarkable: cocos2d-x v3.0 beta

UPDTE: 
   Thank you everyone for helping me, right now I be able to fix it,
The caused of the error is I add this line:

```
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(listener, 1);
```

and forgot to add this line when we finish using _eventDispatcher:

```
_eventDispatcher->removeEventListener(_touchListener);
```

Comment: on button click for switching back and forth u can use CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene( HelloWorld::scene1);

Comment: I have try but it doesn't work, thanks for reply